# Is * the right way to allow all origins in CORS?

Tags: node.js, cors

Does `*` work as the CORS "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value to allow all origins?

I'm getting the error:

> ```
> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://54.***.***.77:2222/login. 
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the 
> requested resource. Origin 'http://debugging.website.biz' 
> is therefore not allowed access.
> ```

But I am using `*` for the value to allow all origins. I want to know if this is a valid way to do it. If it is, I'll have to look elsewhere for my problem.

Comment: It is the correct way.

Comment: Some browsers block "all origins" as a security risk. So if you need to support all browsers you can't support "all origins" regardless of syntax. This was security policy the last time I looked and it may or may not change in the future which is why I'm not including this as an answer to prevent people downvoting my answer 5 years from now :)

Comment: Are you sure the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header is actually on the response? Can you verify in the JavaScript console that the header is actually there? Chrome is getting pretty good at reporting CORS errors, and the error makes it sound like the header isn't there.

Comment: @monsur it confuses me how that header is "attached" to the response, so it's hard to answer that. Do you know of any question that covers it?